# Getting used read and write capacity units from DynamoDB operations

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The DynamoDB API offers ways of getting the consumed capacity units for each operation, by including a `ReturnedConsumedCapacity` value of `TOTAL` or `INDEXES`, see for example the request syntax for [UpdateItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#API_UpdateItem_RequestSyntax).

Doing so means that a `ConsumedCapacity` field is included in the response of the request, which among others has the fields `CapacityUnits`, `ReadCapacityUnits` and `WriteCapacityUnits`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ConsumedCapacity.html

However, regardless of what value I use for `ReturnedConsumedCapacity`, I never seem to get the individual `ReadCapacityUnits` and `WriteCapacityUnits` fields, only the total `CapacityUnits` field.
I can't find anything in the docs suggesting why this happens and if/how it's possible to request these fields to be set.

Are these fields deprecated or no longer supported?
Or are they only included for provisioned tables and not for on-demand tables (for some non-evident reason - this is not about the *provisioned* capacity but the *consumed* capacity so I don't see why that would make any difference)?

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases `ReadCapacityUnits` and `WriteCapacityUnits` are equal to `CapacityUnits`, as a read request never consumes write capacity and vice versa.

So instead of returning values the same value in multiple keys, you get returned the more generic `CapacityUnits` value.

Comment: This is true for `get`, `query` etc, but not for batch and transactional statements. It also doesn't explain why AWS defined fields for something that is never assigned any values...

Comment: What is not true for BatchWrite or Transactions?